# Setting up cronjob 000webhost

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to set up a cronjob on the 000webhost servers.

This is the command line for the cronjob I use.
It should refresh every hour but it doesn't (I set up a write do my database to check)

NOTE: For some strange reason I can't change the "php -f /home/a2902119/" part.

```
php -f /home/a2902119/public_html/database/KlassementRefresh.php
```

This is the php page I'm trying to run.

```
<?php

// Incudes
require_once '../includes/klassementFetcher.php';

//Clearing the Check Table
$con = mysqli_connect("url","host","pswd","user");

//Database Connection Check
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    break;
}

// Fetching Klassement
    //H1 - H1P
    klassementFetch("heren1k","http://kovv.mavari.be/xlsRangschikking.aspx?&reeks=H1");

    //H2 - H3P
    klassementFetch("heren2k","http://kovv.mavari.be/xlsRangschikking.aspx?&reeks=H3A");

?>
```

When I type in the link to the php page everything works like it should, so I'm pretty sure something's wrong with the cronjob's definition.

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: http://www.000webhost.com/forum/before-registration/27272-cron-job.html scroll to the bottom post.

Comment: @Dagon maybe you could copy & paste the content of the relevant post as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy the following into a file, save it as cron_caller.php
PHP Code:

```
<?php
file_get_contents('http://night-city.comeze.com/cron.php');
?>
```

Upload that file into your '/public_html/' folder.

Next, login to 000Webhost.com (http://members.000Webhost.com), select 'Go to cPanel' for the appropriate site.

Scroll towards the bottom of the page, second last panel, labelled Advanced, select Cron Jobs.

Next to the 'php -f /home/a1234567/' put in public_html/cron_caller.php

Set when you want Cron to activate

Then click Add

And you're done.

Comment: why do you need the cron_caller.php? Why cant you call directly the cron.php?