# How to setup cron job in 000webhost (free account)

Tags: cron

I have a website in 000webhost.com (free account) to house some php scripts. In the website, it mentioned that cron-job is available for free accounts as well.

I follow the instruction and setup the cron job as per the below links:

[Setting up cronjob 000webhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948650/setting-up-cronjob-000webhost)

The accepted answer mention in the question does not work now.

Be specific, this is what I have done:
1. Login my 000webhost and click the Cron jobs in the dashboard
2. Update the cron job manager by adding php -f /home/a357xxxx/public_html/test.php for 10 minutes of everyday, everymonth

There is nothing happens for a day after the setup. However, I can run the php script if I run this through the browser so it should not be the php script issue.

I tried to ask the customer support in 000webhost first but they told me that they can only support me if I am a ‘paid’ member. They told me their forum is under maintenance and that’s why I cannot register and ask through the community.

Is there anyone who has experience of setting up cronjob in 000webhost that can share with me?
I am also thinking of moving out 000webhost if I cannot setup cronjob. Do anyone have any recommendation on the free hosting site with PHP+MYSQL+Cron job?

Comment: "does not work" **HOW**?

Comment: thx Marc, should have made this more clear. After I setup the Cron Jobs Manager in 000webhost, there is no cron job running. However, there is no error if I directly access the php script through browser